# Data for loop not accessing all the information

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, for-loop

I have an array of objects: measurments. (do not comment on my spelling)
I'm trying to access each object in the array and have them available in an input to change: [HTML Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFfBt.png)

However it's not working the way I want it to. Every input is the last measurementModel I added to the database.

```
  measurementModel: Measurment = new Measurment;

  measurments: Measurment[] = [];
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.measurementService.getAllMeasurements().subscribe(
      (data: Measurment[])=>
      {
        this.measurments = data;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.measurments.length; i++) {
          this.measurementModel = this.measurments[i];
          console.log(data[i]);
          
        }
        // this.measurementModel = data.forEach((element) =>{
        //   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element))as typeof element
        // })
      }
    )


  }
```

just for clarity this is my HTML for the inputs

```
<div class="card-header"> 
        Measurements
      </div>
      <form (ngSubmit)="createMeasurement(measurementsForm)" #measurementsForm="ngForm">
        <div class="input-group" *ngFor="let  measurment of measurments">
          <input 
          type="number" 
          class="form-control"
          name="inches"
          step=".01"
          #inches="ngModel"
          [ngModel]="measurementModel.inches"
          (ngModelChange)="measurementModel.inches = $event"
          >
          <input 
          type="number" 
          class="form-control"
          name="cm"
          step=".01"
          #cm="ngModel"
          [ngModel]="measurementModel.cm"
          (ngModelChange)="measurementModel.cm = $event"
          >
          <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">UPDATE</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button">DELETE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Honestly I don't know why its doing this because when I print to console each measurementModel appears [measurementModel print to console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjsGj.png)

I'm trying to get each measurementModel to show up on the inputs.

Comment: What should the data from `getAllMeasurements()` look like? I guess what I mean is what does a Measurment object look like?

Comment: @swhitmore its the image at the end:
{measurementId: 1, inches: 34.5, cm: 87.63}
{measurementId: 2, inches: 0, cm: 0}
{measurementId: 3, inches: 9.251968503937007, cm: 23.5}

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs bind to the measurementModel which is in the for loop (and thus contains the value of the last list item).
Try using the value from the *measurment* declared in your *ngFor*.

Comment: I tried that. Still having the same problem. All of my data appears in my console but not on my page.

Comment: I've looked into it and created a working example. The missing thing is the name property inside your input fields that get created by the ngFor loop. Those have all the same name which causes the wrong behaviour.
Setting the name like this: `name="inches-{{ measurment.measurementId }}"` fixes the problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uohddf?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Still not working. The data is partially binding. I used the bellow to check input fields

updateMeasurement(form:any){
    console.log(form);
    console.log(form.measurmentId);
    console.log(form.inches);
  }


it recognizes everything put the measurmentId:

{measurementId: 1, inches: 34, cm: 86.36}
sidenav.component.ts:85 undefined
sidenav.component.ts:86 34

Comment: Not sure what you want to describe with your latest comment, could you provide a code example?

Comment: - When I check the console:
`<input _ngcontent-mrv-c51=""... ng-reflect-name="inches-" ng-reflect-model="23">`
- `<input _ngcontent-mrv-c51="" ... ng-reflect-name="cm-" ng-reflect-model="58.42">`
- notice the measurmentId isn't in the name tag
and if I print the object to console:
`1. {measurementId: 1, inches: 23, cm: 58.42}
2. undefined
3. 23`
1 is the object
2 is the measurmentId
3 is inches
[my gitHub](https://github.com/itimeye/tech-pack-backend/blob/968096b9922b07e5afff06079029aa083f483f41/src/app/components/sidenav/sidenav.component.html)

Comment: I think it is a typo that is causing the error: You are calling in your code `measurmentId` looking at the JSON object in the screenshot from your question there it is called `measurementId` with the correct spelling.

Comment: yep! I posted on reddit and they helped me find it. I was driving myself insane